# ASP MVC HttpPostedFileBase always returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase

I have this code in my HomeController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewRequest(int? id, FormCollection form, HttpPostedFileBase   uploadFile)
{
     if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/Files"), fileName);
            uploadFile.SaveAs(path);
        }
        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");    
}
```

And my NewRequest view is this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewRequest", "Controllers", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
    {
        <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    }
```

The problem is that the uploaded file, .txt file f.x. is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your given code is fine. The only case I can think otherwise is you route config is probably not right.

I've tested with this config and it worked like a charm.

```
      routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NewRequest",
            url: "Controllers/NewRequest",
            defaults: new { controller = "Controllers", action = "NewRequest" }
            );
```